# windows server domain controller has two names

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

I changed my domain controller to something else and now all the computers in the network see two computers for the same server (one with previous name and one with current name). Both of the hosts lead to the same file system. Weirdly I can also ping to both of the host names.

How can I remove the previous name?

Comment: What steps did you take to rename the DC?

Comment: I went to System Properties > Computer Name > Change... Then I restarted.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a lot more involved in renaming a DC than that. Check out this article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794951%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I don't have any of the fields for FRS and DFS Member Object.

Comment: After a restart, the domain name became unaccessible but still visible...

Comment: @D34DM347 that link doesn't say there is any more to it. It says renaming from system properties is a case of ["change the name, click OK"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794805(v=ws.10).aspx), that renaming this way is less preferred but only leads to a longer delay for replication, and that renaming a domain controller is a common task that has more effect on administration and less on client access...